# Disable swipe in one direction for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionView inside a cell.  The collectionView swipes in a horizontal direction.

Inside the collectionView I call this function:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    print(offset)
}
```

When the offset sits at 0, there is no need for the user to swipe left as there is nothing to see in that direction.

How can i disable scrolling in a single direction, temporarily, whilst the offset sits at 0? In this case, disabling scrolling to the left while scrolling to the right remains enabled.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the cell with the collectionView sits inside another cell of a collectionView,  both of which scroll horizontally. I want to disable scrolling on the child cell and enable scrolling on the parent cell at the same time.  So, when scrolling horizontally for the collectionView inside the child cell is no longer enabled, the parent cell begins to scroll.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    return cv
}()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
                    // Other cell here to swipe to when user cant swipe collectionView inside child cell.
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ParentCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ParentCell
        return cell
    }
}

}
```

ParentCell:

```
class ParentCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    return cv
}()


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ChildCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChildCell
    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}


}
```

ChildCell:

```
class ChildCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.tag = 1
    return cv
}()


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    print(offset)
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force the offset using :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == myNotScrollingView {
        //you will never bounce to left
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = max(0,scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do like

```
 // create one global float value for get the every scroll
 var previousX: Float = 0.0
```

set the **tag** for your parent and child collectionview, then access based on tag

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

if scrollView.contentOffset.x < previousX {
      if  scrollView.tag == 1 // set your tag
    {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousX), y: CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.y))
}
else {
    previousX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
}
    }
}
```

**upadte**

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 if scrollView.contentOffset.x < previousX {

      var cell: UICollectionViewCell? = (UICollectionView.viewwithtag(1) as? UICollectionViewCell)



      if  cell.tag == 1 // set your tag
    {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousX), y: CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.y))
}
else {
    previousX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
}
    }
}
```

**upadte 2**

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

 if scrollView.contentOffset.x < previousX {

      var cell: UICollectionViewCell? = (UICollectionView.viewwithtag(1) as? UICollectionViewCell)



      if (cell is ChildCell)
    {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousX), y: CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.y))
}
else {
    previousX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
}
    }
}
else if (cell is ParentCell) {
//Another custom cell
 }
 else {
//General cell
}

}
```

Comment: I'm confused how the tag works. If i set `collectionView.tag = 1` inside the child cell, the outcome is still the same of where I can't scroll left but the parent view doesn't scroll.

Comment: @luke - can you add some  more code , it is easy to resove

Comment: @luke - i added the another option also

Comment: @luke - r u understand the logic for get the tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137130/discussion-between-luke-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake with my edit. To make things a little more complicated, I am attempting to scroll horizontally in the collectionView inside the `ViewController` rather than the parent cell.  The parent cell actually scrolls vertically, whilst the child cell and view controller scroll horizontally.

Comment: i think you try the parallex scrolling